# Zeppelin with Kubernetes. SPARK_HOME is not specified in interpreter-setting for non-local mode

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-zeppelin

I have a Spark cluster (Master + 2 Workers) in a Kubernetes cluster (Minikube).

I want to add Zeppelin in my k8s cluster and configure it to use my Spark cluster.

So I tried to do it using either the [Zeppelin 0.8.1 image from apache/zeppelin](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/zeppelin/tags), or [another image built on Zeppelin 0.9.0-SNAPSHOT (still in develop)](https://hub.docker.com/r/cambridgesemantics/contrib-zeppelin/tags)

I followed the official [Zeppelin documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-SNAPSHOT/quickstart/kubernetes.html) (that requires a Zeppelin 0.9.0 at least, even though it has not been released yet ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ )

What I did :

- Pulling Zeppelin docker image
- Building Spark docker image
- Downloading the zeppelin-server.yaml from the documentation
- Editing it so that he have correct path to my local Spark image and Zeppelin image
- kubectl apply -f (spark & zeppelin yaml files)

I then browse my Zeppelin Notebook, and try to run a small spark test to see if it works, but I get the following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: SPARK_HOME is not specified in interpreter-setting for non-local mode, if you specify it in zeppelin-env.sh, please move that into interpreter setting 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.launcher.SparkInterpreterLauncher.setupPropertiesForSparkR(SparkInterpreterLauncher.java:181) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.launcher.SparkInterpreterLauncher.buildEnvFromProperties(SparkInterpreterLauncher.java:63) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.launcher.StandardInterpreterLauncher.launch(StandardInterpreterLauncher.java:86) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterSetting.createInterpreterProcess(InterpreterSetting.java:698) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ManagedInterpreterGroup.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(ManagedInterpreterGroup.java:63) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(RemoteInterpreter.java:110) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:163) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:131) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:290) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:402) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:75) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:121) 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:187) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

First of all, I see that the error come from the function `setupPropertiesForSparkR()`, even though I don't use Spark R.

But the main thing on which I am lost is that, since I use Zeppelin and Spark docker images, I have no idea how to set my SPARK_HOME and what value should it have.

Notes :

- I use Spark 2.4.0
- I also tried to build Zeppelin image manually, but using the source that are in development, the build fail)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure environment variables using:

```
docker run --env SPARK_HOME=/path ...
```

Also you can create a volume with your Spark cluster

```
docker run --env SPARK_HOME=/pathInCluster -v /pathYourSparkCluster:/pathInCluster ...
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand exactly what is expected for 'pathYourSparkCluster'.
Using the Dockerfile from the Apache Spark repo (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile), what should it be ?
And isn't the line `ENV SPARK_HOME /opt/spark` doing the work ?

Comment: You need to specify SPARK_HOME which is where spark installed.

I understand that your SPARK_HOME is outside zeppelin docker and you can conect your spark with your zeppelin with a volume.

In your zeppelin docker, /opt/spark/ exists and have a spark instalation?

Comment: No. There is no /opt/spark in my Zeppelin docker, and I don't think that Spark is included in the Zeppelin docker. It is the zeppelin-server.yaml (you can find here https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/k8s/zeppelin-server.yaml) that use both the Zeppelin image and Spark image.